# How to apply dictionary to a dataframe column that contains numpy array in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a `pandas data frame object` column where every row is a `numpy array`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'UNIGRAMA': {0: array(['on', 'line', ' atenção'], dtype='<U13'),
                              1: array(['futurar', ' filhar', ' preparar'], dtype='<U12'),
                              2: array(['compromisso', ' educação', ' student'], dtype='<U11')}})

UNIGRAMA
0   [on, line, atenção]
1   [futurar, filhar, preparar]
2   [compromisso, educação, student]
```

I want to apply a `dictionary` to every word of this `numpy array` (if the word doesn't exist, I need to keep the original word). And it has to bring only the unique words from the final result

Here is my `dictionary`:

```
dicionario2 = {'compromisso': 'commitment',
              'filhar' : 'student', 
             'futurar' : 'futuro',
              'on'   : 'on-line',
              'line' : 'on-line'}
```

My desired result:

```
unique
0   [on-line, atenção]
1   [futuro, student, preparar]
2   [commitment, educação, student]
```

What I have tried so far:

```
df['UNIGRAMA'].explode().replace(dicionario2, regex = True).groupby(level=0).agg({'unique'})
```

But it doesn't bring only unique words.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please replace the image of the df snippet with a df snippet. Try: df.head(5).to_clipboard(sep=','). It's much easier to help if we have data to work with.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how to make this df. Every row is of this kind when I access `df['UNIGRAMA'][0]`  `array(['compromisso', 'aprendizagem', 'atenção'], dtype='<U19')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `explode()`,`replace()` and `groupby()`:

```
df['UNIGRAMA']=df['UNIGRAMA'].explode().replace(dicionario2, regex=True).groupby(level=0).apply(np.unique)
```

output of `df`:

```
    UNIGRAMA
0   [commitment, aprendizagem, atenção]
1   [futuro, preocupação, preparar]
2   [commitment, educação, student]
```

Sample dataframe used by me:

```
from numpy import array
df=pd.DataFrame({'UNIGRAMA': {0: array(['commitment', 'aprendizagem', 'atenção'], dtype='<U13'),
  1: array(['futuro', 'preocupação', 'preparar'], dtype='<U12'),
  2: array(['compromisso', 'educação', 'student'], dtype='<U11')}})
```

Comment: Thanks!! I saw that I need to use `regex = True` in `replace` to work when I have more than one word in the original vector to be replaced. Moreover, can I create a numpy array with only unique values? I tried to play a bit with `unique`, but it didn't work. I edited the question for you to see this behaviour.

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira so you want only unique values  per row like say a row contain an array `[commitment, aprendizagem, atenção,atenção]` so you want that it become `[commitment, aprendizagem, atenção]`

Comment: That's it. It happens because two different words can become two equal words after apllying the dictionary

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira updated answer(Instead of applying `np.array` we apply `np.unique`)....kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: It, unfortunately, didn't work when I used the function in the updated `dataframe` and `dictionary2` in the question. The first resultant line is `[ atenção,  on-line, on-line]`. It should be `[ atenção,  on-line]`

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira It's working on my system so here is another way after running `df['UNIGRAMA']=df['UNIGRAMA'].explode().replace(dicionario2, regex=True).groupby(level=0).apply(np.unique)`the above code try `df['UNIGRAMA']=df['UNIGRAMA'].map(np.unique)`

Comment: It still doesn't work for me (even after using `map(np.unique)`). It is strange. Because the code makes sense.

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira check that are they actually unique?.....I mean it can be `['atenção',  ' on-line', 'on-line']` so `' on-line'` and `'on-line'` are 2 different unique words

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira If you want to remove that as well use `df['UNIGRAMA'].explode().replace(dicionario2, regex=True).str.strip().groupby(level=0).apply(np.unique)`